# Spring MVC entry point

Tags: spring-mvc

I want my project to use more than one controller. My question is, how do I navigate from one controller to another and what should I do about having a standard home page for my users to land on? Should this be a separate "homeController"? I don't understand how this should work. The "Spring in Action" book doesn't go into enough details to explain this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a single controller working?  Are you using annotations?  You should provide some more information and what you have so far in order for people to provide help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different Controllers (Java classes) with the `@Controller` annotation, depending on what you want to do is the URL associated with the method defined in the Controller, for example:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        //code to process for the /home url
    }
    // More code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In servlet-context.xml check

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.package.controller" />
```

And use

```
@Controller
```

In class you want to be controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dispatcher servlet to delegate to different controllers.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>your-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>your-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now depending on your `@RequestMapping` bindings in your controllers, the `DispatcherServlet` will decide where to route requests.

Answer (score 0):

Also please check the spring mvc showcase on github. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

Answer (score 0):

If your web is needs a common landing page like login.jsp you can do it like following way.
Configure you dispatcher servlet in web.xml as follows.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>public</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>public</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pub/*</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you should have a dispatcher servelt call public-servelt.xml where you handle the login requests for all users.It should contains configs like this.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.web.controller.secure" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/pub/"
        p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
        p:synchronizeOnSession="true" />
```

And then in your index.jsp where the common landing place of web app, put a jsp forward to hit above dispatcher servelt as follows.

```
<jsp:forward page="/pub/login" />
```

note : In your controller you need to have /login mapping in a get method as follows.

@RequestMapping(method = {GET, HEAD}, value = "/login")
    public String loginHandler(.......){}

This is how normally achieve a common landing page through a spring controller.